# C# get info about a Windows process after it was finished

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.8, windows-process

For a long time, I've been looking for a way to get info about a Windows process which has been finished having only its `PID`.

Does anybody know if it's possible at all? If yes, then how I can do it?

Many thanks.

Comment: Has an ended process PID?

Comment: For example, it started, you got its PID and then it exited itselves

Comment: I really don't think this information is kept alive after the process is killed.

Comment: You need to attach a process class to that pid while its running (Process.GetProcessById) then you can listen to the Exited event or check the HasExited property regularly.

Comment: Or just do a Process.GetProcesses to get all running processes and check if your expected PID is still in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Process.GetProcessById(Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessbyid?view=net-6.0). But according to docs you should get a ArgumentException if the process is not running.

Quoted from docs:

> **Exceptions**
>
> ArgumentException
>
> The process specified by the processId parameter is not running. The identifier might be expired.

Comment: I would not get process info getting this exception, don't think it makes sense

Comment: Then as for _"Does anybody know if it's possible at all?"_ - the answer would be: Nope, not after the process is gone.

Comment: When its about a crash. Then letting windows create a crashdump on exit for those might be helpful for post mortem debugging.